# C++ Win32- Responding to Key Presses

Tags: c++, win32-process

I'm trying to make win32 app that i simulate that I press the `C` key on the piano, keyboard No 60, with the following call: `midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD (0x090 | 0 | (60 << 8) | (64 << 16)));`

and when releasing the key no 60 do with the following call: `midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD (0x080 | 0 | (60 << 8) | (0 << 16)));`

The problem is that when I press the button, I hear the sound only once. and only a single case works when I run the program.

How can I do that the sound is repeated as long as I press. and how can do to make a long melody plays.

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
{
    switch (wParam) {

    case VK_LEFT:
        midiOutOpen(&hMidiOut, -1, 0, 0, 0);
        // Set instrument to 0 = Acoustic Grand Piano
        midiOutShortMsg(hMidiOut, DWORD(0x0C0 | 0 | (0 << 8) | (0 << 16)));
        midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (65<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
        break;

    case 'S':
        midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (62<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));   
        break;

    case 'D':
        midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (64<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
        break;

    case 'F':
        midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (65<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
        break;

    case 'G':
        midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (67<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
        break;

    case 'H':
        midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (69<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
        break;

    case 'J':
        midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (71<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
        break;

    case 'K':
        midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (72<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
        break;
```

Comment: As a side note, you should consider using a C++ [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead of a C switch statement.

Comment: @Tom: good point. And even in plain C this could be done more elegantly with a loop and an array :)

Comment: Your example code works for me. The note is played and fades out like a piano stroke. Perhaps some other portion of your code is causing your problem. Also, don't forget to end the note on WM_KEYUP. You can do this by sending the same message with a volume of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could store the keys states (using a bool array, maybe) and do the playing in the message processing loop.